# Sapply and apply behaviour in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Consider the following `df`:

```
structure(list(GID7173723 = c("A", "T", "G", "A", "G"), GID4878677 = c("G", 
"C", "G", "A", "G"), GID88208 = c("A", "T", "G", "A", "G"), GID346403 = c("A", 
"T", "G", "A", "G"), GID268825 = c("G", "C", "G", "A", "G")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like this:

```
  GID7173723 GID4878677 GID88208 GID346403 GID268825
1          A          G        A         A         G
2          T          C        T         T         C
3          G          G        G         G         G
4          A          A        A         A         A
5          G          G        G         G         G
```

And the following function:

```
f = function(x){
  ifelse(x=='A',x<-1,x) 
}
```

Using `apply` everything runs well as I expect:

```
    apply(df, 1,f)

          1   2   3   4   5  
GID7173723 "1" "T" "G" "1" "G"
GID4878677 "1" "C" "G" "1" "G"
GID88208   "1" "T" "G" "1" "G"
GID346403  "1" "T" "G" "1" "G"
GID268825  "1" "C" "G" "1" "G"
```

But if I use `sapply` or `lapply` all the values are converted to 1:

```
> sapply(dfn,f)
     GID7173723 GID4878677 GID88208 GID346403 GID268825
[1,]          1          1        1         1         1
[2,]          1          1        1         1         1
[3,]          1          1        1         1         1
[4,]          1          1        1         1         1
[5,]          1          1        1         1         1
```

I read from the documentation that `lapply` and `sapply` applies `FUN` to every element. Why is everything being converted to 1? Is there anything to do with R coercing integers to strings ? Please help.

One other aspect which I don't understand is why with this new function I have only a `vector` with 5 elements instead of a `dataframe` filled with 'G':

```
    f2 = function(x) x<-'G'

> sapply(dfn,f2)
GID7173723 GID4878677   GID88208  GID346403  GID268825 
       "G"        "G"        "G"        "G"        "G" 

> apply(dfn, 1,f2)
  1   2   3   4   5 
"G" "G" "G" "G" "G"
```

Comment: `ifelse(x=='A',x<-1,x)` seems really weird.  Did you mean`ifelse(x=='A',1,x)` ?  Similarly I think you want `f2 = function(x) 'G'`

Comment: FYI, if you try `class(apply(df, 1, f))`, you'll see that your data is now a `"matrix"`, no longer a `"data.frame"`, since the first thing `apply` does is [convert its argument to a matrix](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/apply.R#L29).

Comment: When you do `ifelse(x=='A', x <- 1, x) ` you are actually overwriting `x` with `1` for the `'A'` cases, then returning the new `x` (`1`) for all the non-`'A'` cases as well. `ifelse(x=='A',1,x)` as shown in Ben's comment will allow `sapply(df, f)` to work fine.

Comment: Moreover, I guess you just need `df[df == 'A'] <- 1`

Comment: @thelatemail, actually ... it's not overwriting `x` with 1 for the `'A'` cases, it's overwriting `x` with just `1` (length 1). Try `x <- 1:10 ; ifelse(x < 5, x <- 1, x); x`. There is no case ever I think assignment *inside* of an `ifelse` comes anywhere close to what might be expected or desired.

Comment: @r2evans - true, i'm being a bit sloppy with my description there.

Comment: thanks for all comments. @Ben Bolker `f2 = function(x) 'G'` followed by `sapply(dfn,f2)` or `apply(dfn, 1,f2)` returns me the same output. Why it doesn't return a 5x5 matrix with 'G' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- apply takes df or matrix as input, and outputs=>vector, list, array
- lapply takes df, list or vector as input, and outputs=> list
- sapply takes df, list or vector as input, and outputs=> vector or matrix

1st question. If you use

```
apply(df, 2,f)
```

you will also get a table full of 1s. R is not converting strings to integers.

2nd question. Try this as 1 is used for rows, and 2 is for columns.

```
apply(df, 2,f2)
```

Comment: To your list, add that `sapply` can return a `list` in addition to a vector, matrix, or array.